# Are there any BR Weapons in Halo 3 ODST?

Tags: halo-3-odst

I've played through Halo 3 ODST Campaign and didn't see any BR Weapons.

Are there any BR weapons in Halo 3 ODST?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What weapons are available in Halo 3 ODST?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/403628/what-weapons-are-available-in-halo-3-odst) - While the answer adds interesting info about BR, the question is more-or-less encapsulated within the linked question

Comment: @Wondercricket No, it doesn't. The BR isn't a normal weapon in Halo 3 ODST. So it's not on that list from the other question. You would think that the BR is of course in Halo 3 ODST like any other Halo game, but no. It's actually not playable at all in Halo 3 ODST. It only comes as an easter egg in Halo 3 ODST.

Comment: @Wondercricket Also. That question did not exist when this question was asked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There aren't any playable or usable BR weapons in the Halo 3 ODST campaign, but there are actually a BR in the ODST campaign as an easter egg.

It is in a cutscene where it is wielded by an NMPD officer as can be seen in this screenshot from the cutscene:

[image: NMPD officer holding a BR in Halo 3 ODST]

This specific BR in the cutscene is a "BR55 Heavy Barrel Service Rifle" as can be seen by these close-up photos of that same NMPD officer holding it:

[image: NMPD officer holding a BR in Halo 3 ODST][image: NMPD officer holding a BR in Halo 3 ODST][image: NMPD officer holding a BR in Halo 3 ODST]