# What weapons are available in Halo 3 ODST?

Tags: halo-3-odst

As the title states, I want to know which playable weapons (Human, Covenant, Brute, etc.) are available in Halo 3 ODST?

Comment: Please stop taking widely available information elsewhere and reformatting it into a question/self-answer format. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Human Weapons

### Assault Rifle (MA5C ICWS)

[image: Halo 3 ODST - Assault Rifle (MA5C ICWS)]

Gas-operated, fully-automatic projectile rifle capable of sustained continuous fire. Accurate if used in short, well-aimed bursts and is otherwise ferociously powerful at close range.

### Shotgun (M90A CAWS)

[image: Halo 3 ODST - Shotgun (M90A CAWS)]

The UNSC's resident close-quarters assault weapon. One shot to your foe's head is likely to take it clean off with a blast from one of these semi-automatic shotguns.

### Rocket Launcher (M41 MAV/AW)

[image: Halo 3 ODST - Rocket Launcher (M41 MAV/AW)]

Equipped with a 5x scope, this Rocket Launcher has a high degree of both destructive force and accuracy. Though it packs a punch, it has the burden of limited rounds before reloading as well as a minimal carrying capacity. Use your rockets wisely.

### Spartan Laser (WAV M6 GGNR)

[image: Halo 3 ODST - Spartan Laser (WAV M6 GGNR)]

A directed energy weapon. Its battery conservation scheme requires the user to give its target fair warning during the brief charge lag. A zoomed scope will assist in aiming, but the quickness of the blast will leave many missing their targets anyway, unless truly skilled. However, it is still one of the most powerful portable armaments in the UNSC arsenal.

### Sniper Rifle (SRS 99D AM)

[image: Halo 3 ODST - Sniper Rifle (SRS 99D AM)]

The primary sniper rifle system used by UNSC forces. The clip will leave some to be desired, but the power will not. Equipped with a scope capable of 5x and 10x zoom, great for the long range, incognito, battles.

### Sub Machine Gun (M7/Caseless)

[image: Halo 3 ODST - Sub Machine Gun (M7/Caseless)]

Sub-machine Guns, while not accurate over long distances, are particularly effective at close quarters. What this model lacks in accuracy, it makes up for in magazine capacity, with a rather large clip.

### Magnum (M6G Pistol)

[image: Halo 3 ODST - Magnum (M6G Pistol)]

A recoil-operated, semi-automatic handgun. Accurate and utilitarian in design, it is the ideal sidearm for a wide variety of USNC troops, packing a strong punch for such a small gun.

## Covenant Weapons

### Plasma Pistol

[image: Halo 3 ODST - Plasma Pistol]

This Covenant weapon is capable of quickly firing low-powered shots, or of charging a single high-powered shot which can rapidly deplete energy shielding.

### Needler (Type-33 GML)

[image: Halo 3 ODST - Needler (Type-33 GML)]

Razor-sharp crystalline projectiles with a combined explosive property are fired from this elaborate Covenant weapon. The projectiles follow the desired target, like a homing missile, but to a lesser extent. A very destructive weapon when the enemy cannot get away (the needles will track targets, but not from a very long, or very short distance away).

### Plasma Rifle (Type-25 DER)

[image: Halo 3 ODST - Plasma Rifle (Type-25 DER)]

A common, light plasma weapon favored by Covenant forces. The plus factor? You never need to reload this gun. The downside? There will be brief pauses from shooting if the gun is left to overheat from constant, non-stop firing.

### Beam Rifle (Type-50 Sniper Rifle)

[image: Halo 3 ODST - Beam Rifle (Type-50 Sniper Rifle)]

The Covenant equivalent to the sniper rifle, a hand-carried particle beam weapon, with an adjustable 5–10x scope. Again, no reload is required, has a minor drawback of brief pauses from shooting if the gun overheats from a happy trigger.

### Mauler

[image: Halo 3 ODST - Mauler]

Razor-sharp crystalline projectiles with a combined explosive property are fired from this elaborate Covenant weapon. The projectiles follow the desired target, like a homing missile, but to a lesser extent. A very destructive weapon when the enemy cannot get away (the needles will track targets, but not from a very long, or very short distance away).

### Brute Shot (Type-25 GL)

[image: Halo 3 ODST - Brute Shot (Type-25 GL)]

This vicious and dangerous rifle is favored by Brutes and based on their native, pre-Covenant technology. Shoots sharp, inaccurate spikes that allow you to mow down your foes quickly.

### Energy Sword (Type-1 EW/Sword)

[image: Halo 3 ODST - Energy Sword (Type-1 EW/Sword)]

Favored by Elites, this energy weapon is more dangerous than its ceremonial nature implies. Allows for easy slaying of any foe while also offering a somewhat defensive property if swung at the same time as one is swung in your direction. Only take it out when your enemy is near; you will be shot down if someone spots you from afar.

### Gravity Hammer (Type-2 EW/Hammer)

[image: Halo 3 ODST - Gravity Hammer (Type-2 EW/Hammer)]

Favored by Brutes, this weapon is as much a symbol of leadership as it is a weapon. The brute force behind this weapon allows you to pummel your enemies. Offers a defensive property, allowing you to bat projectiles away with a simple swing. What you miss, is the force of gravity caused by the swing is likely to hit. It can actually deflect rockets if timed correctly.

### Carbine (Type-51 Carbine)

[image: Halo 3 ODST - Carbine (Type-51 Carbine)]

An unusual Covenant projectile weapon, firing shielded radioactive rounds. This semi-automatic has a 5x zoom allowing for some mid-range precision shooting. A single-shot rifle.